# How do I keep my code open in the shell with a pass command in the main() function?

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to learn how to build a web browser bot as half learning half project for someone else and I've hit a snag.

The site I'm using as guide has:

```
def main():
     pass
```

Which he claims keeps the shell window open do he can run various functions like get x,y cords of the mouse position and take screen shots.

However when I run my code exactly as he has it in the guide it immediately opens and closes.

What I don't want is something like, "make it so pressing enter closes shell instead", what needs to happen is the window stays open so I can enter various functions.

What am I doing wrong? Am I suppose to just import the code in a different shell and run the functions outside it?

The code:

```
import os   
import time
import ImageGrab

x_pad = 0   
y_pad = 61

def screenGrab():   
    box = (x_pad,y_pad,x_pad+1919,y_pad+970)    
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)    
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) + '.png','PNG')

def main(): 
    pass    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

The guide is: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games--active-11117

Comment: The last four lines just check if the code was imported or executed directly as first argument given to the Python executable. If executed directly, it calls a function that is empty. In summary, the code does nothing. My advise: Run your code from an existing terminal or use `python -i ...` to enter interactive mode after execution.

Answer (score 1):

You have three ways:

1. Start the intepreter with the `-i` option, as suggested by [Ulrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968182/ulrich-eckhardt) in the comments:

   ```
   python -i my-script.py
   ```

   This way, the interpreter will be left open as soon as your script finishes execution and a prompt will be shown.
2. Use [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). This is often used for debugging, and has a different interface than the usual Python prompt. If you're not familiar with it, it might not be the best option in your case. Replace `pass` with these two lines:

   ```
   import pdb
   pdb.set_trace()
   ```
3. Use [`code`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html). This will give you an interface much more similar to the usual Python shell and can be an alternative to `pdb` if you're not familiar with it:

   ```
   import code
   code.interact()
   ```

By the way, you were not doing anything wrong per se. The `pass` statement is not meant to "halt Python and start a prompt", it's just needed as a filler for functions or loops with an empty body.